# Should I use an Angular front end with a .Net backend, distributed as a desktop app via Electron?

Tags: .net, angular, electron

I'm attempting to make a CRM from scratch, and so far have settled on using Angular as a front end, using EntityFramework to handle my CRUD operations and call my stored procedures. However, I've hit a road block when it comes to distributing the app. If possible, I want to distribute as a desktop app. After doing a bit of research, I've landed on Electron, but the documentation I've found seems to be outdated.

Is this a viable route to go down, or should I be using a different combination of software?

Comment: Depends what exactly you expect from the framework. Electron is by far the most popular choice, but this question needs more details for an accurate answer.